# undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass after Rails upgrade 4.2.8 from 4.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I recently upgraded rails from 4.0.1 to 4.2.8. After upgrading I am getting below issue. I tried to resolve by upgrading devise gem but it didn't help.

```
undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

[image]

Comment: The issue seems to be from peek gem not devise. You are on rails 4.2.8 not 4.2.5 (as you said in description). peek gem seems to be tested on 4.2.7.1. See if you downgrade rails to a lower version than 4.2.8 works.

Comment: Downgrading the rails version causing another issue. Instead of that I downgraded gem peek itself. Thank you for you response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this issue](https://github.com/peek/peek/issues/116) `peek 1.1.0` introduced some changes that work with rails 5.

It looks like `peek 1.0.1`, https://github.com/peek/peek/blob/v1.0.1/lib/peek/railtie.rb, does not have that change so, locking `peek` to `1.0.1` should fix the issue .